# How to convert a ResourceSet to a List of names using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `ResourceSet` with all the `Bitmap` resources of my application. I want to convert it to a `List<string>` with the names of the resources. Using a `foreach` loop, this code works for me:

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (var resource in resourceSet)
{
  var entry = (DictionaryEntry)resource;
  List.Add(entry.Key.ToString());
}
```

How can I do this using Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(item => item.Key.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks so much. I get an error: "System.Resources.ResourceSet" does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Resources.ResourceSet' could be found".

Comment: @Sipo Do you remember about namespace `using System.Linq` ?!

Comment: Yes... I am using .NET 4.5. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @Sipo Sorry, I forgot that the ResourceSet implements non generic IEnumerable. So I edited answer please check it.